# Umbraco custom viewmodel

Tags: umbraco

I would like to pass the data to the view, I created a viewmodel inheriting from RenderModel but when I run to the error "Element" Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel  "does not contain the definition" Topic "

ViewModel:

```
namespace Umbraco12.Models
{
    public class Home : RenderModel
    {
        public Home(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture)
        {
        }

        public string Topic { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Home(RenderModel model)
        {

            var home = new Home(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);
            home.Topic = "aloha";
            //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
            return View("Home", home);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<Home>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
<h1>@Umbraco.Field("topic") : @Model.Topic</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DocumentType Alias is "Home".

I would also call your model something different to just Home as it could clash and give an ambiguous error.

Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {

            var home = new Home(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);
            home.Topic = "aloha";
            //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
            return View("Home", home);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco12.Models.Home>

@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
<h1>@Model.Topic</h1>
```